# What's the term describing someone who's obsessed with his/her own face?

Tags: single-word-requests

I was think of [narcissistic](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Narcissism) but this is a more general term describing someone's self-obsession with various aspects of himself/herself.

I was wondering if there's not a more specific term, describing the fact of being self-obsessed with one's own face.

Comment: *Narcissistic* It is derived from a mythic Greek character who was so enamored of the reflection *of his face* in a pool of water that he was trapped and turned into a flower. How is that not specific enough?

Comment: @bib agreed, this is what I was remembering of the term's etymology as well (and Wikipedia confirmed it). However, nowadays this word is used to mean more than that, it's meant to describe someone who's obsessed with his/her own body, mind, etc.

Comment: Then perhaps *Grimhildistic* for the evil [Queen Grimhilde](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Evil_Queen_(Disney)) in the tale of Snow White who is obsessed with her face in the Magic Mirror.

Comment: faciphilia. faciem (face in latin) + philia. (made up word)

Comment: @ermanen That sounds more like someone who is obsessed with faces in general, not just their own face. Perhaps _autofaciphilia_?

Comment: @Barmar, that’s not a very pleasing Greek-Latin-Greek mixture, though. If we’re already making up words, we might as well stay all in the Greek aisle and call it ***autoprosopophilia***. That has the advantage of being almost impossible to say, too. ;-)

Comment: It seems odd that you ask for a term, but you discount outright the most specific and well-known term available.

Answer (score 3):

There probably isn't a term specific to *faces* but someone who is obsessed with their own looks is often described as "vain":

> vain — excessively proud: excessively proud, especially of personal appearance

"Narcissistic" etymology comes from a story about [Narcissus](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Narcissus_%28mythology%29)'s obsession with his own reflection. But modern usage just describes anyone who is self-obsessed:

> narcissism — self-admiration: excessive self-admiration and self-centeredness

The key difference between "vain" and "narcissistic" is that "vain" very specific implies an obsession of one's *physical appearance*. The stereotypical description is of someone who always pauses to look at themselves in a mirror.

I am not aware of specific forms of vanity for different parts of the body.

Answer (score 1):

Callomania: [an abnormal psychologic condition characterized by delusions of personal beauty.](http://medical-dictionary.thefreedictionary.com/callomania)

Answer (score 0):

I prefer the term "autofaciphilistic" to describe someone who is an autofaciphile, or a person with an irrational attraction to their own face. However, an overly vain person of great beauty would not classify as an autofaciphile. If that is the case, I would go with narcissistic.

Comment: Welcome to ELU, Tim. Can I assume you are making autofaciphile up?